# Pandas sort by one column and index

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe like this I'm trying to figure out how to reorder it depending on the **stations** (index) and **depth** column , so it gives me first all the **d1st1** with all different depths (1, 5, eu, z90, MLD), then **d1st3** again with the same depth order etc.

Any ideas?

[image: BB9]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I really don't know how to convert it to a dictionary or post it otherwise, sorry, I'm quite a beginner in coding @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need a way to order your depth column. I'd suggest creating another column to hold your depth values as numbers.

Let's say we first create a function to convert your data, and call your dataframe "df". The function depends on how your values on the depth column are organized. If they're all in a regular pattern, you can try something else, but if your values are organized like in your example, this could do the trick:

```
def _depth_index(x):
    if x=='1m':
        return 1.0
    elif x=='5m':
        return 5.0
    elif x =='90':
        return 90.0
    elif x=='eu' or x== 'MLD':
        return 0.0 #Not sure what 'eu' or 'MLD' stands for... Might want to return something else.

    else:
        return 0.0 # Default value
```

After that, apply your function to the new column in your dataframe:

```
df['indexed_depth'] = df['depth'].apply(lambda x: _depth_index(x))
```

And just sort your values:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['stations', 'indexed_depth'], ascending=[True, True])
```

Comment: thank you, but it gives me a key error already for the 'stations', should I somehow change it to a normal column before applying the sort_values operation?

Comment: Perhaps. It should work as an indexed column, but if you're having problems, try resetting the index beforehand, as in: df = df.reset_index(drop=False)